# attr_reader only working in some environments

Tags: ruby

This applies also to `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor`.

I've been playing with some simple Ruby code recently and the following snippet does not work in all environments I've run it:

```
class Human
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

hank = Human.new("Hank")
hank.name
```

This should output "Hank", which it does in my command line irb. In Textmate2 and Aptana Studio 3, nothing outputs when I run this code. All three work as expected if I explicitly define the reader:

```
def name
  puts @name
end
```

When I play in the Aptana terminal and my usual terminal and type:

```
$ ruby -v
```

They both appear to use the same version: ruby 2.0.0p451. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

attr_reader just doesn't do what you think it does.

try

```
puts hank.name
```

rather than

```
hank.name
```

and  you'll see the output.  irb is a special case, it shows you the return value of the last statement executed.  ruby on its own won't do that, it only prints things you explicitly tell it to print.

Comment: It seems so obvious when you say it. Thank you.